# mongodb - how to insert a new key/value on each array's element if not present (with mongo query)

Tags: mongodb

I would like to update each elements (object) in an array of a company.

Here my actual data :

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("60d31024860ce0400b586111")
  contracts: 
   [
     {
       name: 1.pdf
       url: "https://someurl"
       createdAt: 2021-06-23T10:42:44.594+00:00
     }
     {
       name: 2.pdf
       url: "https://someurl"
     }
     {
       name: 3.pdf
       url: "https://someurl"
     }
   ]
}
```

I would like to add a defined date on each object (in contracts) that has no "updatedAt" key.

Here what I tried :

```
db.companies.update({ _id: ObjectId("60d31024860ce0400b586111"),"contracts.createdAt": { $exists: false } },{ $set: { "contracts.$.createdAt": "test" } })
```

but I got this error :
"The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query."

I have also tried this and it works, but I don't wanna query by file name. I just wanna add "createdAt" on each elements found that has no "createdAt"

```
db.companies.update({ "contracts.name": "2.pdf" },{ $set: { "contracts.$.createdAt": "atest" } })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use the [filtered position operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/):

$ - updates the first matched array element
$[] - updates all the matched elements with a  specific condition

The specific condition is mentioned in the `arrayFilters` key.

```
db.students.update(
   { },
   { $set: { "contracts.$[element].createdAt" : "atest"} },
   { multi: true,
     arrayFilters: [ { "element.createdAt": { $exists: false } } ]
   }
)
```

`multi` - true is to apply the operation on all the **matching documents**.

Also notice, how the first query parameter is empty, which means the query runs for all documents. I used it based on the second query you wrote but you can also add in an `ObjectID` query there.

Comment: Worked as expected. Thanks you so much! 
Thanks for your explanations too!